# IMO selection process in Pakistan

Tags: math-contests

I have been searching for the International Math Olympiad(IMO) qualification process in Pakistan and I found out that students take the NMTC(National Mathematics Talent Contest) paper which to get into you have to have certain marks on your O levels. Then 50 of the top students are chosen which are invited to a training camp. The people are narrowed down until 5 are left. However, according to my knowledge, some parts have changed and I couldn't find reliable sources to confirm what has changed.

What I am asking for is essentially the qualification process and the sources which are important for the information.

Comment: Regarding whether or not this question is on-topic, please see https://matheducators.meta.stackexchange.com/a/666/77

Comment: You could try emailing the [official contact for Pakistan](https://www.imo-official.org/country_info.aspx?code=PAK) from the IMO page. No source will be more reliable than that.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about mathematics education.